# downgrade spyder

Tags: package-management, upgrade, qt, bug-reporting, spyder

I have just upgraded ubuntu. As a result, spyder is not working anymore. This the error:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 33, in <module>
   sys.exit(load_entry_point('spyder==4.2.1', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder')())
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 213, in main
   mainwindow.main(options, args)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3624, in main
   mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3482, in create_window
   main.setup()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 803, in setup
   self.completions = CompletionManager(self)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/plugin.py", line 97, in __init__
   plugin_client = Plugin(self.main)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/plugin.py", line 50, in __init__
   self.installer = KiteInstallerDialog(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 287, in __init__
   self._integration_widget = KiteIntegrationInfo(self)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 58, in __init__
   image = image.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
 scaled(self, int, int, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
 scaled(self, QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

This seems to be a bug ([here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701475))

what do you suggest?
Can I downgrade spyder? is if a feasible solution?

Best

Comment: This is this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spyder/+bug/1968479

Comment: This is a Python 3.10 problem, not a Spyder problem necessarily.  The only way to 'fix' this is likely a Python downgrade which is not safe, so if you need Spyder you probably should use 20.04 not 22.04.  HOWEVER there is a workaroudn in the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spyder/+bug/1968479/comments/4  Try this workaround first instead of using the spyder package in the repositories,.

Comment: @ThomasWard I have Spyder 5.3.1 currently installed in  Ubuntu 22.04 (as shown  in the below screenshot) in a Python virtual environment which has Python 3.10 as its Python version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114520/error-when-starting-spyder-on-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`This is a Python 3.10 problem, not a Spyder problem necessarily.` which was posted as a comment to the main question by Thomas Ward seems to me to be correct because I was not able to successfully run the Spyder 5 application in either macOS or Ubuntu except by installing it in a Python virtual environment.

Follow these instructions to install the latest version of Spyder (currently Spyder 5.x) in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

1. Install Python 3 virtual environment creator.

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
   ```
2. Run `python3 --version` to show the python 3.x version. In
   Ubuntu 22.04 the default Python 3.x version is Python 3.10 which I will use as an example in the next step.
3. Create a Python virtual environment for Python 3.

   ```
   virtualenv -p python3.10 venv  
   source ./venv/bin/activate
   ```

   The new Python virtual environment for python3.10 will be created in the `venv` directory which is located in the current directory.
4. Install the latest version of Spyder.

   ```
   pip3 install spyder
   ```

[image]
<sup>**Spyder 5.3.1 in Ubuntu 22.04** (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Worked perfectly, Spyder 5.3.2 came right up.

Comment: I remember thinking when I installed Spyder 5  Let pip automatically install all the dependencies with the compatible versions and abracadabra, it's installed.